# onepagecheckout - logic after login

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, login, customer-account, onestepcheckout

I cannot understand the logic of what magento is doing after login submit action in onestepcheckout page.

My problem is that after login the user is redirected to My Account and I want the user to stay in the same onestepcheckout page.

Can anyone throw some light here?

```
<form id="login-form" action="<?php echo $this->getPostAction() ?>" method="post" class="checkout-step-body checkout-step-style form form--checkout clearfix">


function onepageLogin(button)
{
    if(loginForm.validator && loginForm.validator.validate()){
        button.disabled = true;
        loginForm.submit();
    }
}

 <customer_login>
    <observers>
      <loadCustomerQuote>
        <class>checkout/observer</class>
        <method>loadCustomerQuote</method>
      </loadCustomerQuote>
    </observers>
 </customer_login>
```

Comment: Try this admin>System>Configuration>Customer>Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in setting make it NO

Comment: I want the customers to go to MyAccount in the normal login. That's the reason the redirection is set to YES in that config section.

Comment: Do you using any extension for onepage checkout?

Comment: No extensions. Just a custom onepagecontroller doing minor stuff for the moment, nothing related with login.